# Why form is never submitted with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My form is

```
<form id="dataForm">

</form>
```

the button that is clicked is

```
<button id="btnAddSave" type="button">
    ButtonText
</button>
```

and the Jquery used is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnAddSave").click(function () {
        alert("1");
        $("#dataForm").submit(function (e) {
            alert("2");
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);

            var url = "/save";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    })
});
```

In the example above, the first alert is displayed, but not the second one.
What is going on wrong here? How can i fix it?

Comment: Does the server side POST return a 200?

Comment: The form is not submitted on the server

Comment: Ok, I see it now. you are attaching a form submit listener in a click handler, The form submit actually never happens (there is no trigger for this).

Comment: So how can i fix that? You see, I do not wish to put actions within the form tag

Comment: In your click handler you can not use form.submit(). It is excess of code, and it never runs since you never actually submitted your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the submit handler is not firing because it is attached when the click handler fires.
You can simply just remove all the submit code as such:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnAddSave").click(function () {
        alert("1");
        alert("2");

        // e.preventDefault(); -> this does nothinng for a button type button
        var form = $("#dataForm");

        var url = "/save";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you bind two event handlers in each other? 
Go with .click or .submit, no need for both. The code itself should work.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comment, this is a working example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnAddSave").click(function () {
        alert("1");
            alert("2");
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $("#dataForm").serialize();

            var url = "/save";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: form,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
    })
});
```

Comment: if you found it useful, can you please mark it as an answer so the others find it useful.